# Why is db:create making development DB when all other indications are it's in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, passenger

I have a strange problem.

I have the following database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: MyDB_production
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: 
  password: 
  database: test        # or whatever the name is
  encoding: UTF8

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: MyDB_development
  pool: 5
  username: dazzaroonie
  password:
```

My environment.rb has:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Chatrpix::Application.initialize!
```

My Passenger VHost is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ...
    <Directory /Users/dazzaroonie/Sites/newapp/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        RailsEnv production
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So I should be in production mode yes?

I run `rails console` and I get:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.0)
2.1.0 :001 >
```

So, it seems to think it's in production, however, when I run rake db:create it's creating the development database and not the production.

I've been looking at this for hours, and no closer to knowing why ...

I don't have an `ENV` set using my `.bashrc` etc ...

So, how does every other part of Rails know I'm using production mode, and yet not rake?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you set RAILS_ENV after loading application.rb. That could cause confusion in the code. Try setting RAILS_ENV before loading application.rb.